# Как вставить переменные в js

Tags: javascript

Подскажите пожалуйста, как вместо цифр 166, 155...... вставить переменные?

```
var xValues = ["Italy", "France", "Spain", "USA", "Argentina"];
var yValues = [166, 155, 44, 24, 15];
var barColors = [
  "#b91d47",
  "#00aba9",
  "#2b5797",
  "#e8c3b9",
  "#1e7145"
];

new Chart("myChart", {
  type: "pie",
  data: {
    labels: xValues,
    datasets: [{
      backgroundColor: barColors,
      data: yValues
    }]
  },
  options: {
    title: {
      display: true,
      text: "World Wide Wine Production 2018"
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Сначала необходимо создать сами переменные, а затем добавить их в ваш массив `yValues`.

```js
let first = 1;
let second = 2;
let third = 3;

var yValues = [first, second, third];
```

Также рекомендовал бы вам использовать для создания переменных не `var`, а `const` и `let`.

Comment: Спасибо! Благодаря вашему ответу нашел то, что искал :)